# Receiving an Error when Copying file over

Tags: windows-10, powershell, file-transfer, xcopy

I have a script that i run against 1K systems. In the script I copy a file over to the systems' temp folder. 1 or 2 systems out of 1K systems return an error of "Invalid drive specification" when I use xcopy. I have tried to copy-item, but receive an error of "the network path was not found". I ran dir & get-childitem, but receive an error of "Cannot find path '\computername\c$\temp' because it does not exist". I can enter a pssession on the system and go to the folder. I can rdp into it and directly and put the file into the folder from the share (gui). When I enter a pssession and try to copy it from within the pssession the computer acts as if the share drive path to the file doesn't exist. It returns an error of "Cannot find path '\sharedrive\folder\folder\file.ps1' because it does not exist". The system is Win 10 running powershell version 5.1. It is just a couple of systems that are causing an issue.

Has anyone seen an issue like this?

```
while($true){

    $script = "\\path\folder\folder\SystemInfo.ps1"
    $local = (get-item "$script").fullname.split("\")[-2]+"\"+(get-item "$script").fullname.split("\")[-1]

    $computers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Computers OU,OU=OU Container,DC=com" | Where-Object {$_.enabled -eq $true}).name | sort
    $computers += (Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Computers OU,OU=OU Container,DC=com" | Where-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -like "*server related*" -and $_.enabled -eq $true}).name | sort
    $count = 0


    $computers | ForEach-Object {
        $alive = Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Quiet -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $checked = $null
        $checked = (ls "\\path\folder\folder\Software_List\$_.csv").LastWriteTime
        $Date = (get-date).AddDays(-1)

        if ($alive){

            $count += 1

            if($checked -lt $Date -or $checked -eq $null){

                write-host "$_ Online and info needs to be updated`t" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor "Green" -BackgroundColor "Black"

                $copy = xcopy /y /f $script "\\$_\c$\temp\$($local.split("\")[0])\"
                #$copy
                if($copy -notlike "0*")
                    {
                    $psexec = psexec -s -h -d \\$_  powershell.exe C:\temp\$local -accepteula

                    if($error[0] -like "*with process ID*")
                        {
                        write-host "Success`t" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor "DarkGreen" -BackgroundColor "Black"
                        ""
                        }

                    else
                        {
                        write-host "$_ Copy Failure`t" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor "DarkMagenta" -BackgroundColor "Black"
                        ""
                        }
                    }
                else
                    {
                    write-host "$_ had a Copy error`t" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor "DarkMagenta" -BackgroundColor "Black"
                    ""
                    "$_" >> "\\path\folder\folder\Invalid_Drive.txt"
                    }

                }
            else
                {
                write-host "$_ Online, but info does not need to be updated`t" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor "Yellow" -BackgroundColor "Black"
                ""
                }

        }

        else
            {
            write-host "$_ is offline`t" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor "Magenta" -BackgroundColor "Black"
            ""
            }

    }
    write-host "$count systems are online"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600
}
```

Comment: can you please post your script? otherwise we would just guess

Comment: @SimonS I have added the script.

Comment: Maybe that  the administrative shares are turned off on your Windows workstations or servers?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the script and the error you are receiving. Also xcopy is not a PowerShell command, it is a copy tool that comes with Windows. If you want to copy using a PowerShell cmdlet you should use:

Copy-Item

or similar to below

copy-item .\documents\ -destination .\my-file-$(Get-Date -format "yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss")